# modify date format on json array in php

Tags: php, json

My issue is that I have array how contain value with dateTime format but I would like modify this value with a format Y-m-d. I tried a lot of thing of issue here but nothing work when I encode my json.

Now I have that :

```
[contacts] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                     [createdAt] =>2020-01-29T17:00:04.159+01:00
                   )
)
```

And I would result like

```
[contacts] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                     [createdAt] =>2020-01-29
                   )
)
```

My php code is :

```
$contacts=$result[contacts];
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {

$time = new DateTime($contact['createdAt']);
$date = $time->format('Y-m-d');
echo '<br>' .$date; //that show the date format I want
}
//that don't show correct format
 $json=json_encode($contacts);
 print_r($json);
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to pu my php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify you `$contact` array with [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) `&`:

```
foreach ($contacts as &$contact) {

    $time = new DateTime($contact['createdAt']);
    $contact['createdAt'] = $time->format('Y-m-d'); 
}
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/tNjq6)

Comment: That work ! thanks a lot, i didn't know we can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign value in your contact array by just doing below changes in your code

```
        foreach ($contacts as $key => $contact) {
            $time = new DateTime($contact['createdAt']);
            $date = $time->format('Y-m-d');
            echo '<br>' .$date; //that show the date format I want
            $contacts[$key]['createdAt'] = $date;
        }
```

it will reassign your new date value in your existing element